# setattribute run once on setinterval function

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval, setattribute

im trying to show random image every 1 sec its an image inside a div without src attribute :

```
<div class="D">

<img>   

</div>
```

here is the css code :

```
 .D{

  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  left: 35%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;

  }
  .D img{

  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  }
```

i have an array that contains src of 4 diferrent images from the folder and with Math random im picking a random number from 0 to 3 as the array index and repeat the function with *setinterval* :

```
var inp = document.querySelector('.D');
var p = document.querySelector('.D img');
var Src= ['Imgs/home.png','Imgs/gps.png','Imgs/bell.png','Imgs/box.png'];
var RndomFrom0To3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);


function ChangeImgSrc() {

p.setAttribute('src',Src[RndomFrom0To3]);


};


setInterval(ChangeImgSrc,1000);
```

the src changes but once and it stop in the same image  what im i doing wrong ?

Comment: `var RndomFrom0To3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);` assigns a value to *RndomFrom0To3* once, it doesn't get updated. You need to recalculate it on each call, e.g. `p.setAttribute('src', Math.floor(Math.random()*4))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call random generator too in each call

```
function ChangeImgSrc() {
    var RndomFrom0To3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
    p.setAttribute('src',Src[RndomFrom0To3]);


    };
```